# Lucene search query dynamic update and add additional query fields?

Tags: java, lucene

I am working on facet search, one of the requirement is to select id values from facet drop-down. ***id*** values will be in the range 1-digit to 16-digit, but in data these ***id*** values will be from 8-digit to 16-digit.

I have to support following use-cases, both from UI and REST api.

Sample Query:

```
http://localhost:7001/app/api/search/meta.type:typeA AND id:value?results=facet:id
```

Requirement is to correct query, based on values passed for attribute ***id***.
If passed value's length is less than 8 digits. i.e. if the  is less than 99999999, I have to do a regex search, otherwise normal matching search.
Ex:

> 1)
>   actual:       +meta.type:typeA +id
>   modified      +meta.type:typeA +id:8 +id:8*
>   2)
>   actual        +meta.type:typeA +id:4567
>   modified      +meta.type:typeA +id:4567 +id:4567*
>   3)
>   actual        +meta.type:typeA +id:12345678
>   modified      +meta.type:typeA +id:12345678 +id:12345678*
>   4)
>   actual        +meta.type:typeA +id:123456789
>   modified      +meta.type:typeA +id:123456789

Query type is BooleanQuery.

I have tried following, but it has no effect on query value. (Adding another value to the query as the first one wouldn't return anything)

```
Query [] termArray = new Query [1];
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.add(new TermQuery(new Term("id", queryKeyValue + "*")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
termArray[0] = Query.mergeBooleanQueries(bq);;
query.combine(termArray);
```

I am using Lucene 3.6 libraries.
I have a doubt, this kind of updates on query are possible or not.
If this is valid scenario and can be achieved, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `TermQuery`.  `TermQuery` is a simple query exactly matching the given text.  If you are manually constructing a query, there isn't a query parser to handle that sort of thing for you, so you have to select the correct types of queries yourself.

[`PrefixQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html) is the one you are looking for:

```
bq.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("id", queryKeyValue)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

I don't think this will do what you want, however.  The difference between

```
+meta.type:typeA +id:12345678
```

and

```
+meta.type:typeA +id:12345678 +id:12345678*
```

Is actually quite trivial.  You will not get more results that way, because you still *require* an exact `id` match.  I believe what you are looking for is probably more like:

```
+meta.type:typeA +(id:12345678 id:12345678*)
```

Comment: `+meta.type:typeA +(id:12345678 id:12345678*)`    
I think this should be the correct one.

Comment: `+meta.type:typeA +(id:12345678 id:12345678*)`  
I have followed the query to use this format. This solved my problem. Thanks.